# Mac wouldn't start up after I tried to fix a Mac App Store issue

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, startup

I have a MacBook Pro (13 Inch, End 2010) running OS X El Capitan.

I had a bug with the Mac App Store, searched on the Apple forum, and got advice to remove a folder `var/folders/zz`.  I moved it to the Trash and then the Mac was blocked on the start-up loading bar.

Comment: Have you already tried to boot your Mac in [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)?

Comment: @JohnnyDrama I can't, I have rEFInd

Comment: I'm trying to reinstall OS X right now, just to let you guys informed ;)

Comment: Well, after reinstalling OS X, it still doesn't startup

Comment: When booting your Mac, hold down ESC, that should override any automatic boot selection you may have set in rEFInd. Then select your Mac partition, but instead of pressing enter, press fn+F2, that should give you some advanced options. Try to see if you can boot into either Safe Mode, or Single User Mode.

Comment: @Siguza I finally found a way to disable rEFInd, so, I booted my Mac, but it is blocked at the end of the loading bar

Comment: Does anyone knows how to move the folder from the Trash to its original location with Recovery HD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Time Machine from Recovery HD to solve my problem, it perfectly reinstalled everything.

Comment: Would you like to accept your answer as suggested in http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer?

Comment: Yes, it's just a bug @DAVincent It tells me that I have to wait until tomorrow

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the times on the answer.  Thanks.